# AWUS036AC (rtl8812au) – ›Association request to the driver failed‹ after restarting wpa_supplicant.service

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+, driver

I am using an AWUS036AC wifi dongle to connect to the internet. I installed the drivers following [this instructions](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au).

When I restart my `wpa_supplicant@INTERFACE.service` I get this error message:

```
Association request to the driver failed
```

When run `iw dev` afterwards, it shows me that the interface is still connected to the last ssid (which is obviously not true). I also see that the interface is switching channels, when I run the command again. So my guess is that there is another process interacting with the device. **Is there a possibility to find out which processes are using an interface?**

I have to set the interface down `sudo ip link set INTERFACE down` to be able to restart the service.

My `wpa_supplicant@INTERFACE.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target

# NetworkManager users will probably want the dbus version instead.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I

[Install]
Alias=multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant@%i.service

# /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@INTERFACE.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw %I set txpower fixed 500
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %I -j MASQUERADE
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o %I -j MASQUERADE
```

Running `wpa_supplicant` with `-d` manually, I find this error messages:

```
nl80211: MLME connect failed: ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Explicitly disconnecting before reassociation attempt
wpa_driver_nl80211_disconnect(reason_code=2)
```

Maybe there is to find more relevant; the output is a bit overwhelming.

Did anyone had the same issue? Is it a bug? Any guess how to work around this?

Comment: I don't know what `wpa_supplicant@AWUS036AC.service` is doing. It's not enough for an answer but you can try to run **wpa_supplicant** from the command line with debug output. Run `systemctl cat  wpa_supplicant@AWUS036AC.service`, take the command from `ExecStart=` (should start wpa_supplicant) and run it from the command line with additional option `-d`. You will get many more details and maybe you will get an idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround:

When I stop the `wpa_supplicant@INTERFACE.service` and run `iw dev` afterwards, it shows me that the interface is still connected to the last ssid (which is obviously not true, I also see that the interface is switching channels, when I run the command again). I have to set the interface down `sudo ip link set INTERFACE down` to be able to restart the service.

So I added `ExecStopPost=-/sbin/ip link set %I down` to the wpa_supplicant@INTERFACE.service.d/override.conf` and now it works.

I would be glad to have an explanation for this.

**EDIT:**

Since I updated the driver to version 5.3.4 the issue is gone. So it seems that there was a bug in the driver, although I don't have any evidence for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's nothing to do with your adapter. It's all about the configuration how you do it. And surely it's not a bug either.

I have had that issue once. Configure your wpa manually by going to network-configuration.  Restart your network manager and see what it says.

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Here's the link i had followed [**Network Manager**](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=234618)

if that didn't work then check firmware compatibility **rtl-8812u-firmware**

Comment: I don't use `NetworkManager` and I don't want to use it.